# Bootstrap Datepicker startDate and endDate

Tags: html, bootstrap-datepicker

This is a date range picker. This is already working and validating `startDate` and `endDate` input values. My question is how can I put a value to the `endDate` field?

Ex. if `startDate` is selected at **2020-2-27**, the `endDate field` will be filled up with the value **2020-2-28**.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="startDate">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="endDate">
```

This is my code. I am using the bootstrap datepicker

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date(new Date().setYear(start.getFullYear()+1));

$('#startDate').datepicker({
    endDate   : end
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $('#endDate').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date($(this).val()));
}); 
$('#endDate').datepicker({
    startDate : start,
    endDate   : end
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $('#startDate').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date($(this).val()));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ***enddate*** value on `startDate` change Like this

```
$('#startDate').on('change',function(){
var today=$('#startDate').val();
var myDate = new Date(today);
 myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
$("#endDate").datepicker("setDate", myDate);
})
```

To remove the `datepicker` selector

```
$(function(){
$("#endDate").css('pointer-events', 'none');
})
```

Here is a updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/x1n5acjL/7/

Comment: almost ok but. end date is filling up the values. But I can still select the `startDate` value  on the `endDate` field. how to disable?

Comment: apologize for the late replay I have updated the code and fiddle as per your needs do check and consider making it answer if that is a solution